# How do I create VSDX file using Java?

Tags: java, xml, visio

How to create [Microsoft Visio VSDX file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/JJ228622.aspx) using Java corresponding to a diagram? This diagram can be in the form of VDX file or XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be easy to work directly with Visio in Java. C# and Office PIAs (Primary Interop Assemblies) are the way to go. You could then use JAB to integrate your java and C# solutions.

Comment: i think you mean "jaxb" not jab to integrate your java and c# solutions.

Comment: Java Access Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need api at some point for vsdx file operations in java , you may use ["JAVA VISIO DIAGRAM LIBRARY "](http://www.aspose.com/java/diagram-component.aspx)

Comment: in aspose we can save file as vdx and some other forms.. not as vsdx file.. as far as i have checked export api's provided by it doesn't include vsdx..